# How do I find out Java's heap size on my computer?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I'd like to be able to get the size of the heap as a variable. I don't need to change the size, just know what it is and have it in a variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried this before so I can't guarantee this will work, but try `Runtime.totalMemory()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can get application run time information

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

   rt.freeMemory();
   rt.totalMemory();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,
the java.lang.Runtime.freeMemory() method returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine. Calling the gc method may result in increasing the value returned by freeMemory.

```
      Also,reading about runtime information about Java is useful sometime when your application is struggling in getting resources.
```

You may try this code:`

```
class HeapTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from Heap\n");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println(rt.totalMemory());
        System.out.println(rt.freeMemory());
    }
```

}
`